# How to enable Remote Logout functionality like Google/Facebook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I already know about access tokens and refresh tokens where you keep access tokens of low expiry and generate refresh token with infinite or longer expiry and use to regenerate access tokens.

My question is how do we implement remote log out functionality to remotely logout from all devices etc. I mean Google provide this functionality. Do we implement it using the same access tokens/refresh token and just invalidating the tokens? I have also seen that some apps log you out when you change your password like Skype. How do these apps handle such work because I don't see how we can accomplish it using tokens without maintaining some kind of state on the server which in my view would defeat the purpose of the tokens.

Comment: Refresh tokens are themselves stateful, you'd store the in something like redis usually. Then when the shorter lived token has expired, you check it against the long lived refresh token to issue a new one. If you want to force the log out of a user, you'd delete the refresh token from state.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that however it still present a window where an unauthorized user have access to the resources even if for 5 minutes. I have seen in applications like Skype, Uber that as soon as I change my password it log me out from other devices instantly. How do they do that unless they invalidate the access token which I don't know is possible without changing the signature and consequently logging out all the users.